# Anderson orthogonality theorem for anisotropic potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, fermions

The  original [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.18.1049) by P.W. Anderson presents the infrared orthogonality catastrophe for the fermionic many-body system in the presence of local scattering potential, e.g. $V(r)=\delta(r)$. The derivation is quite straightforward: one needs to consider the Slater determinant of the free particle wavefunctions (in spherical coordinates):$$\psi=\gamma_{l}j_{l}(kr)Y_{lm}(\theta,\varphi)$$
and the scattered waves with the phaseshift $\delta(E)$ given by the scattering theory. Taking the overlap between them, one may see that it goes to zero with the increasing system size $N$.

What I am interested are absolutely the same derivations, but for the potential that has p-wave, d-wave,... components. It is kind of expected for the orthogonality catastrophe to remain in that case, but I wonder whether there are papers/lecture notes/textbook chapters on that topic. Since I struggled to find them myself I wonder if people have encountered something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonality catastrophe is quite well studied, and rather independent from the basis in which it is considered. The point is that the many-particle ground state without the potential (before the potential is turned on) is orthogonal to the ground state with the potential, which, e.g., means that the X-ray absorption cross-section should be zero (the potential is due to the hole left after light absorption), and has wide-reaching implications for the Kondo problem (here the change in the potential is due the flipping of an impurity spin). In most cases the problem is effectively reducible to a one-dimensional one, so anisotropy is not likely to change much - particularly, if approached from the renormalization group viewpoint.

Specific treatments for anisotropic potentials probably exist, but, the information is scattered among the texts on the many_body theory (e.g., [Mahan](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Many_Particle_Physics.html?id=xzSgZ4-yyMEC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) treats it in the context of X-ray absorption), Kondo effect ([Bickers review](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.59.845) and Anderson's own papers), dephasing/decoherence (e.g., the [paper by Aleiner, Wingreen and Meir](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.79.3740)) bosonization ([Schotte&Schotte](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.185.509)), etc. I give these not as the definitive references, but as directions to explore.

I think the materials on Kondo effect is where it is most likely to go beyond the s-wave approximation: d- and f-shells of impurities are routinely considered in this context, although this field has also developed many methods alternative to the orthogonality catastrophe approach.